# Sort Eloquent Collection by created_at

Tags: php, collections, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table named 'posts' with the columns: 'post_id int primary increments', 'poster_id int' and 'status text' as well as an array named friends with the columns: 'user_id int primary' and 'friend_ids text'.

I need to grab all the IDs in the friends text column which is easy enough using:

```
$friends = explode(',', \Friend::where('user_id', \Sentry::getUser()->id)->first()->friend_ids);
```

Where the data in the text column would look like '1,2,3,' etc.

Then I create an Eloquent Collection object which is also easily done via:

```
$posts = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
```

But the problem is I can't figure out how to populate the collection and sort its contents by the Post object's 'created_at' column.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
foreach ($friends as $id) {
    $posts_ = \Post::where('poster_id', $id)->getQuery()
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
    foreach($posts_ as $post) {
        $posts->add($post);
    }
}
```

I can't figure out if this code would work or not for sorting the entire collection of posts by the 'created_at' column. I would also need to be able to paginate the entire collection easily.

What is the recommended way of sorting the collection?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you want to sort a `collection` you can use the `sortBy` method by given key

```
$sorted = $posts->sortBy('created_at');
```

Also you can apply a callback function on the `collection`

```
$sorted = $posts->sortBy(function($post)
{
  return $post->created_at;
});
```

Hope this helps. For more information on `collections` you can read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-collections)

Comment: Awesome! ☺ In my case, I have more dimensions, so I adapted it to `return $post->type->hierarchy;` and it worked!

Comment: How I can sort by several fields? (I mean, when the value of certain field is the same, sort by other criteria)

Comment: For some reason, when I use this solution, $post is passed as collection itself so I need to call $post->first()->created_at; otherwise I get undefined property exception

Comment: does this really sort by dateTime or in fact sort by created-at string ?

Comment: @shock_gone_wild It sorts by created_at string but still the comparison will work correctly. If you want you can also convert to Unix timestamp `return strtotime($post->created_at);`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It will work as long as the format is  Y-m-d . But if the format of created_at is not ordered by the most significant periods like m.d.Y  the sort order will fail. But with the strtotime() function it will work in every case.

Comment: @shock_gone_wild Yes you are right, I was assuming using default format laravel uses for the timestamps. But to be sure use strtotime()

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to loop through the `$friends` array, you can just use it together with [whereIn](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses) like this

```
$posts = \Post::whereIn('poster_id', $friends)->latest()->get();
```

This replaces the empty collection creation and the `foreach`-loop, and gives you all your friends posts in one Collection sorted by `created_at`

*(the `latest` function is a shortcut for `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')`)*

Answer (score 1):

Sorting with pagination can be implemented like this in Laravel 8:

```
$sorted = $posts->sortBy('created_at');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the latest added posts, you can simply use the "reverse function":

```
$sorted = $posts->sortBy('created_at')->reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two of the simplest ways to sort.

Sort ascending:
`$posts->sortBy('created_at')`

Sort descending:
`$posts->sortByDesc('created_at')`